# json file into pyspark dataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've downloaded a json file, that I'm trying to get it into a DataFrame, for making some analysis.

```
raw_constructors = spark.read.json("/constructors.json")
```

When I make `raw_constructors.show()` , I only get one column and one row.

```
+--------------------+
|              MRData|
+--------------------+
|{{[{adams, Adams,...|
+--------------------+
```

So when I ask for the schema of the json file with  `raw_constructors.printSchema()`

I got this:

```
root
 |-- MRData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ConstructorTable: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Constructors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- constructorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- nationality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- limit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- offset: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- series: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- total: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- xmlns: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm using pyspark.

How can I get the dataFrame with the 4 columns: constructorId, name, nationality, url and get one row per item?

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to flatten everything or you just need  constructorId, name, nationality, url columns ?

Comment: @Suresh you're wright, columns and also their respective rows. Thank you!

Comment: Please give an example of input, output, it would be easier for us to help

Comment: @pltc I've edited my question. I hope it help's a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply using `explode` to break the array down to multiple rows

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .select(F.explode('MRData.ConstructorTable.Constructors').alias('tmp'))
    .select('tmp.*')
    .show()
)

+-------------+----+-----------+---+
|constructorId|name|nationality|url|
+-------------+----+-----------+---+
|           i1|  n1|         y1| u1|
|           i2|  n2|         y2| u2|
+-------------+----+-----------+---+
```